# iOS app: access SMS and Call log

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I read many of the questions on this forum and elsewhere that an iOS app can't access
SMS and call log, also that Apple disabled them for security reasons.

How is this app able to read them?. Did Apple give their app special permissions?

http://www.mobile-spy.com/iphone.html#sms

Comment: Mobile Device Management (MDM) profiles?

Comment: There are APIs available to access the call log etc. but you are not permitted to use them. However it looks like this app is downloaded directly and not via the app store. If that is the case then the app does not have to abide by the app store submission rules.

Comment: @Leo. I was under the impression MDM could only be used within an organization, and if used for other purposes the developer account could be revoked. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @MartinH No idea about terms of use, but I don't see why. MDM vendors provide software for creating profiles. Apple even provides its own tool. MDM profiles have broad reach and little restrictions. This could be based on MDM+VPN to log all traffic and analyze it.

Comment: "but I don't see why". It means companies can develop and sell apps that have additional capabilities than those released on the app store - and additionally apps can bypass Apple's in-app-purchase for example and thus cut the 30% revenue to Apple so that's why I'd be surprised if there isn't some restrictive licensing terms. However it seems this company may be doing that so maybe there isn't. Interesting

Comment: There is an Enterprise Developer option that allows organisations to distribute their own apps to their own devices without Apple oversight/approval.  These apps can use private frameworks etc, but you can't use the Enterprise Developer program to sell apps outside of the App store to non-enterprise users (well, you could, but it violates the agreement with Apple and they have lots of lawyers...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked software only works on Jailbroken iOS devices.  It is not sold through the Apple App Store and not approved by Apple, so it does not need to comply with Apple's restrictions on using private frameworks.  The applications's [web page](http://www.mobile-spy.com/compatibility.html) contains the following disclaimer-

> All iPhones, iPads and iPods MUST be jailbroken prior to installing
>   Mobile Spy. You cannot download or install Mobile Spy if the iPhone is
>   not jailbroken.

Comment: Yes. That is what I found here in the installation instructions.  http://www.mobile-spy.com/iphone-v6.html. Not just Mobile-Spy but every app in that category(http://www.mireview.com/) requires the phone to be jailbroken.